# Windows 10,CUDA 9,: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at ..\src\THC\THCG

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, pytorch

My env configuration:

python:3.6
tensorflow-GPU 1.3
CUDA:9.0
VS:2013
torch:0.4.0

run CUDA 9.0 sample:success

but when I run the pytorch code,I get the error info as follows:

File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 249, in 
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (35) : CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at ..\src\THC\THCGeneral.cpp:70

I have tried reinstall CUDA,but the error still exists

Comment: Can I know your GPU model and version?

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you the GPU driver you have installed cannot cope with the CUDA version you are using. Either update your driver to the latest version or downgrade your CUDA runtime to a version supported by your GPU driver.

Comment: thank you.I reinstall CUDA9.0 and tensorflow,and It works